# using getx get.arguments in flutter breaks when doing a hot-reload

Tags: flutter, arguments, flutter-getx

Using GetX with Flutter, I pass data between parent controller/screen to its child controller/screen using **Get.arguments**.

The issue is that when doing a hot-reload while working on a child Get.arguments, the parent gets re-instantiated with the arguments of the **current** controller/screen.

This issue is described [here](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/1153).

Is that a bug, or something that can't be avoided?
I use the **Get.arguments** in the controllers but still experiencing this issue...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `Get.arguments` get it's value from the previous page, using it directly in your code will normally throw an error saying that it's null on hot reload/restart because it update the state

try saving Get.arguments first in a dynamic variable then use that varibale in your code

Comment: Can you kindly write a small snippet / sample to demonstrate it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the arguments while navigating from the 1 screen to second like:

```
onTap: () {
              Get.toNamed(screen2, arguments: ['ApplicationDemo']);
          },
```

On the 2nd screen/controller, store the arguments in a variable like:

```
var a = Get.arguments;
```

Then use it like:

`Text(a[0].toString() + " " + a[1].toString())`,

Alternatively, you can access it directly like:

`Text(Get.arguments[0].toString() + " " + Get.arguments[1].toString())`;

Comment: This does not work for me. It still giving the error:                                                                            '[]'
Dynamic call of null.
Receiver: null
Arguments: ["std"]   //std as just an argument